# Entity Framework with non-database data source

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

can you use Entity Framework to expose an EDM over data contained in binary files ? or data contained in some obscure data retrieval mechanism ?

Comment: If you just need a solution that doesn't require a server, there are better options (SQLite, SQL CE, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If you can [Write an Entity Framework Data Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789835.aspx) for your file type, then you can use Entity Framework with it.

I can certainly say that it won't be easy though.

Comment: Is it possible to have an EDM that retrieves data from two sources at the same time ? Say, it retrieves 3 tables from an SQL Server database and some data from my file type ?